# NullPointer while using sharedPreference in SplashScreen

Tags: android

I am working on an application where i want to store some data in sharedPreference during splashscreen and then read that data once the main activity loads up. If I save the data from MainActivity the data gets saved and I am able to fetch it back. But If I am trying to save the data in splashscreen, I get nulpointer excpetion. Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.amandeepsingh.loginregisterandother.SharedPreferncesExecutor.save(SharedPreferncesExecutor.java:22)
    at com.example.amandeepsingh.loginregisterandother.SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask$PrefetchData.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask.java:79)
    at com.example.amandeepsingh.loginregisterandother.SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask$PrefetchData.doInBackground(SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask.java:36)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Here is my sample code:

SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask:

```
public class SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask extends Activity{

    //String now_playing, earned;
    private SharedPreferncesExecutor sharedPreference;
    Activity context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        /**
         * Showing splashscreen while making network calls to download necessary
         * data before launching the app Will use AsyncTask to make http call
         */
        Activity context = this;
        new PrefetchData().execute();

    }

    /**
     * Async Task to make http call
     */
    private class PrefetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // before making http calls
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            sharedPreference = new SharedPreferncesExecutor();
            sharedPreference.save(context,"SchoolData","Updated data from Splash Screen");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // After completing http call
            // will close this activity and lauch main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask.this, MainActivity.class);//Here Main activity is the splash screen.
            //i.putExtra("now_playing", now_playing);
            //i.putExtra("earned", earned);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a local variable inside onCreate and assigning it the value of the activity. The member variable context is not modified. It stays null and you get an NPE.
There is no need to create any member variable. You can just do this
Instead of

```
sharedPreference.save(context,"SchoolData","Updated data from Splash Screen");
```

Use

```
sharedPreference.save(SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask.this, "SchoolData", 
               "Updated data from Splash screen");
```

The async task is a non-static inner class of SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask so it already has a reference to the activity.

Answer (score 3):

your class member `context` is null, because in `onCreate`, declaring

```
Activity context = this;
```

you are hiding the visibility of the member class in favor of the local member. To avoid ambiguity you can use `NomeOfYourActivity.this`(`SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask.this` in your case), without assigning any reference. In your AsyncTask change from

```
sharedPreference.save(context,
```

to

```
sharedPreference.save(SplashScreenActivityWithAsyncTask.this,
```